# wpc11 ver 3 with new install of lubuntu

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, sony

I'm trying to conect to wireless via an older sony vaio laptop that is using a linksys wpc11 card, version 3. When I attempt to network connections only a wired connection is listed , tried to manually setup a wifi connection with all the required data but fails to save this information, I don't have an option to connect to different networks in range so im assuming there may be a driver issue, im not certain im a new lubntu user and just looking for some suggestions, I've heard this adapter should work right out of the box so ive reinstalled lubuntu afew times with the same results

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing wifi card driver containing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Then reboot.

If this doesnt work, then reinstall the packages:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: Tried this and still unable to connect to wireless, I am able to setup a wifi connection , there isn't an option to detect networks or an option to connect using the wifi connection, is there a different way I should be trying to connect via wifi

Comment: You can use wicd. `sudo apt-get install wicd wicd-gtk wicd-daemon wicd-cli wicd-curses`